# How to check if CArchive is valid

Tags: c++, mfc

I use the MFC-Serialize function to read / store some values.
If i catch the wrong filename, the Application crash.

I see that is usually because, it try to read beyound the end of the CArchive (file) and returns some unitialized values.

How can I check if CArchive is still valid after extraction? or the end of the CArchive is reached.
Similiar with ifstrem if (is) is >> tmp.

```
std::vector<double> m_vecPoint;

void CTestDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {   // Store
        int AnzT = m_vecPoint.size();
        ar << AnzT;

        for (int i = 0; i < AnzT *&& *ar.isGood()*/; i++)
        {
            ar << m_vecPoint.at(i);
        }
    }

    else
    {   // Read
        int AnzT(0);
        ar >> AnzT;

        for (int i = 0; i < AnzT; i++)
        {
            double pt;
            ar >> pt;
            m_vecPoint.push_back(pt);  // crash occurs here (how to validate pt?)               }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How can I check if CArchive is still valid after extraction?"* - That doesn't make sense. Why would you even care? If deserialization succeeded, you don't need the archive object any longer. If it didn't, it threw an exception along the way (assuming that your serialization code throws exceptions as well). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: The exception occurs between ar >> pt and m_vecPoint.push_back(pt), so it make sense for me.
The exception is  a "floating point underflow" which I can not catch with try..catch.

Comment: I don't understand, why you'd get a floating point exception, when dealing with integers exclusively. That certainly doesn't sound right. At any rate, if you want to error out early, use a versionable schema (see [Serialization: Making a Serializable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00hh13h0.aspx)). Additional information you may find helpful is available at: [TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32wxt301.aspx).

Comment: Good catch, CPoint (=long data) was the wrong example here. Code example corrected with CMyPoint.

Comment: You cannot (de-)serialize `CMyPoint`. For MFC's serialization to work, a class must be declared `DECLARE_SERIAL` to have the serialization members declared, together with `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` in its accompanying compilation unit. This is either not real code, or a bug.

Comment: I have tried this, derived CMyPoint from CObject and declared DECLARE_SERIAL and IMPLEMENT_SERIAL without success. (can't catch the floationg point exception). But thanks for pointing me where te floating point exception occurs. I have now found a solution to avoid floating point exception. I convert doubles in CString and  read / write it with ar.WriteString(str) / ar.ReadString(str).

Comment: Worst idea. Ever. Not only do you lose precision every time you serialize data to disk, it will also occupy more space. And doesn't solve your real issue. It really starts to sound, like your core issue is, that you don't know, how MFC serialization works. If you are serializing objects that aren't declared `DECLARE_SERIAL` (or `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`), then I would assume you have bigger issues.

Comment: There will not be any floating point exceptions as long as you implement proper serialization (i.e. derive from `CObject` and use the `DECLARE_SERIAL`/`IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` macros). **Don't** implement free functions to serialize your objects. Doing so will not store type information (as regular MFC serialization does). Without type information the `CArchive` implementation cannot detect invalid streams. Don't side-step the infrastructure, and you won't have issues like you describe.

Comment: @IInspectable I have tested it toroughly. You are right, CArchive does not throw any exception. However, I need to check if the extracted floating point value is correct. If not the programm crash, in the next code line. How can I validate the double pt, after extractign ar >> pt in the right way?

Comment: You do not have to validate the data, if you are **properly** serializing/deserializing data. It is guaranteed to be valid (as long as you streamed out valid data, obviously). Your real issue are your `operator<<` and `operator>>` overloads, that fail to store/extract type information. In doing so you deprive the `CArchive` implementation of any way to reliably verify stream integrity. Stop breaking things and you won't have to fix them later with a kludge.

Comment: Please, also, don't keep changing the question to something completely different. It's not even clear anymore, which problem you need help with. And it's missing a [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

To avoid floating point exceptions while extracting from CArchive (the programm crashes, despite try, catch handler). I avoid this now by converting floats/doubles in CString and use ar.Write/ReadString(str) inside my >> and << operators.

```
inline Archive& operator<<(CArchive& ar, const CMyPoint& val)
{
    tostringstream os;
    const TCHAR kSep = _T(' ');

    os << val.m_fTemperatur1 << kSep;
    os << val.m_fTemperatur2 << kSep;

    ar.WriteString(os.str().c_str());
    return ar;
}

inline CArchive& operator >> (CArchive& ar, CMyPoint& val)
{
    CString str;
    ar.ReadString(str);

    tistringstream is((LPCTSTR)str);
    tstring sep;
    is >> val.m_fT1 >> sep;
    is >> val.m_fT2 >> sep;

    return ar;
}
```

Comment: And what about different locales? Did you ever heared that some countries have a comma as a decimal point? This code would drive me mad if I would see it in our code...

Comment: That's my own data, that I read back. I have not a problem to read my own data back. But if I or the user accidentally select a wrong file, the programm crash. My only purpose is to avoid a programm crash. This schema worked for me. How do you catch a floating point exception?

Comment: What happens, when one user exchanges a file stored with one locale setting with a user using another locale setting? This is not a solution. It's not even a kludge. It tries to fix a bug that doesn't even have to be by introducing a number of new bugs. As commented a number of times already: Implement **proper** serialization support for your classes, and you won't have any issues. The `CArchive` implementation will know, when it's presented with an invalid stream, provided that you do retain type information in the serialized stream. Your stream operator overloads drop this type information.